# Stack depth Limit INSERT trigger

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, database-trigger

I have this table on PostgreSQL and I'd like to make a trigger that every time I edit one row of the table `publications` the `last_edit_date` is updated to `now()`:

```
CREATE FUNCTION trigger_update_question_timestamp()
  RETURNS "trigger" AS $func$
BEGIN
    UPDATE publications SET last_edit_date = now() WHERE publicationid = NEW.publicationid;
    RETURN NULL;
END;
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER answer_update_question_timestamp AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON publications
   FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE trigger_update_question_timestamp();

CREATE TABLE publications
(
    publicationid SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    body VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL ,
    creation_date TIMESTAMP DEFAULT now() NOT NULL,
    userid INTEGER NOT NULL,
    last_edit_date TIMESTAMP,
    CONSTRAINT body_length CHECK (CHAR_LENGTH(body) >= 10 AND CHAR_LENGTH(body) <= 1000),
    CONSTRAINT "FK_publications_users"
        FOREIGN KEY ("userid") REFERENCES users ("userid") ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

I'm using PhpStorm and when I manually edit a line I get the following error:

```
[54001] ERROR: stack depth limit exceeded Hint: Increase the configuration parameter "max_stack_depth" (currently 2048kB), after ensuring the platform's stack depth limit is adequate. Where: SQL statement "SELECT 1 FROM ONLY "public"."users" x WHERE "userid" OPERATOR(pg_catalog.=) $1 FOR KEY SHARE OF x" SQL statement "UPDATE publications SET last_edit_date = now() WHERE publicationid = NEW.publicationid" PL/pgSQL function trigger_update_question_timestamp()
```

What does this exactly means? Does it have to do with my trigger or any other definition?

Answer (score 3):

Your trigger is recursive, that is, the trigger function executes an `UPDATE` that calls the trigger function again.

The solution here is to use a `BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE` trigger, that modifies `NEW` as follows:

```
BEGIN
   NEW.last_edit_date := current_timestamp;
   RETURN NEW;
END;
```

Comment: What do you mean? @Laurenz Albe 
Something like `BEGIN UPDATE publications SET NEW.last_edit_date = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP WHERE publicationid = NEW.publicationid; RETURN NULL; END; `
It says new of publications does not exist

Comment: No, this is the complete body (I have edited the answer to indicate that). No `UPDATE`, no nothing. All you do is modify the value *before* the row is inserted. Don't forget that it has to be a `BEFORE` trigger.